# OutOfMemoryError while rendering in libgdx

Tags: java

I have to render mesh array in using libgdx in render(). I used handler because every time I'm getting new data in getMeshToRender() method in meshArr array.

```
        onCreate()
        {
          handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);  
          handler.postDelayed(sendUpdatesToUI, 1000); // 1 second
        }

        Runnable sendUpdatesToUI = new Runnable() 
     {
            public void run() 
            {
                //DisplayLoggingInfo();   
                getMeshToRender();
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000); // 1 seconds
            }
        };          

   getMeshToRender()

 {

   .......
    meshArr = new Mesh[numMesh];
   .......
 }
```

in Render() method it initially loads that meshArr but then crashes with OutOfMemoryError.

Any solution will be aprreciable.
Thanks

Comment: IMO, increase heap size.

Comment: I have very big array and it already giving me following error:        Clamp target GC heap from 49.908MB to 48.000MB  . Here, Every second I've to load that array with new values.

Comment: @sans481, While rendering, can I release previous memory? If yes, how?

Comment: I'm running it on android tablet. So how to check that JVM heap size?

Comment: I increased heap size. but still it throwing the same exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple, and only real, answer is to use less memory.

Either you are just using too many different meshes, and you should rethink your whole idea, or you are replacing them and not properly disposing of the old ones.

If you want to release unused meshes, you should use `Mesh#dispose()`